# Issues registering Sqlite driver in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, driver

I am trying to connect to a sqlite database from Java.  I am programming in Windows.  I downloaded the sqlite driver and set the classpath in the windows environment variables.  I get a classNotFoundException when this code is called:

```
   Class.forName(sDriver);
```

where sDriver is "org.sqlite.JDBC"  Here is the stacktrace from the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at com.ib.client.examples.Mydb.setConnection(Mydb.java:49)
at com.ib.client.examples.Mydb.init(Mydb.java:33)
at com.ib.client.examples.Mydb.<init>(Mydb.java:17)
at com.ib.client.examples.Example1.run(Example1.java:40)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems your classpath does not include driver.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which JDBC driver you are trying to use, but the best SQLite JDBC driver i found so far is the one made by the Xerial Project:
http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC

You can find the latest version of the driver here:
http://www.xerial.org/maven/repository/snapshot/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.7.8-SNAPSHOT/

It uses a native driver for Windows (32 and 64 bits), Linux (32 and 64 bits) and MacOS (32 and 64 bits), and falls back to a pure java implementation in the case of an unsupported platform.

All native libraries (dll, so, etc) are included in the driver's JAR file, and you don't need to worry about loading any of them. It will autodetect the right library for you.

EDIT:
If you are trying to run your program from command line, you must specify every jar file in the classpath. Setting their path in the classpath environment variable is not enough.

Example:

```
java YourProgram -cp classes;lib/sqlite.jar;c:\libs\java\lib1.jar
```

Comment: I downloaded this driver, and am still getting the same exception.  I am using the NetBeans IDE.  I tried it with and without having the driver registered un the Services tabs.  I am grasping at straws.

Comment: You need to add the drivers JAR to your project libraries. Goto your project tree (panel on the left side), select Libraries and with the right mouse button do Add Jar/Folder and select the jar file.